# Flex box having 2 div inside it one having canvas inside it

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, addeventlistener, window-resize

**Scenerio:**

Here is my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='textbox'>
   <div id="sibling"></div>
    <div id='canvasParent'>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #000000">
    </canvas>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the js for the same.

```
function outputsize() {
  console.log(canvasParent)
  canvasParent.clientWidth =  textbox.clientWidth - sibling.clientWidth;
  myCanvas.width = canvasParent.clientWidth;
}
outputsize();

new ResizeObserver(outputsize).observe(textbox);
```

Here is the css for the same.

```
#textbox {
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction:row;
  border:1px solid green;
  flex:1;
}

#sibling {
  width:200px;
  border:4px solid yellow;
}

#canvasParent {
  border:2px solid red; 
  flex:1;
}
```

First `div` have 2 child divs namely `sibling` and `canvasParent`, sibling has fixed width, whereas `canvasParent` will take the remaining width.
Currently it is not behaving as expected once we decrease window width then the first `div(sibling)` is decreasing its width, and the width of other div is constant, whereas I want sibling div to remain at its fixed width once user decrease the window width and the other div to shrink/grow.

Here is the [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/nuyawegaki/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output) for the same having css, js for the described scenerio.

**Expectation:**

Once we resize the window, the first `div (sibling)` will keep its fixed width and the other div having canvas inside it will shrink/grow based on window resizing, and the canvas inside it will take its parent width(logic for canvas to take its parent div is already written in js file.)

And resizing works fine, once I remove the canvas element from the second div.
Here is the [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/yunalumode/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output) that show first div to remain at fixed width and other div to shrink/grow once user reduces windows width.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have updated the Question with js and css snippets for the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **CSS Grid** to get the effect:

```css
#textbox {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: ". .";
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

#sibling {
  background: red;
}

#canvasParent {
  background: black;
}

#myCanvas {
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="textbox">
  <div id="sibling"></div>
  <div id="canvasParent">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can design **CSS Grids** here: https://grid.layoutit.com/?id=2NkZ4JY